# A printing quarry

Tags: pgfmath, printing, random-numbers

I know this is not a type setting issue, but if anybody could help with directing me to a site that could help or advise me what type of language I need to learn in order for me to do what I want...I want to set this following page to print out 20 random pages in one go without copying the file on 20 different pages or pressing print every time I run it.

```
    \documentclass{article}
%AdditionCode
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\randomseed}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{pgf}
% \usepackage{showframe}




\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{~\\56 Problem Practice Worksheet}
\rhead{Name: ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ \\}
\lfoot{Number Correct: ~ \Large $\dfrac{~}{20}$}
\cfoot{~}


\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%
%---------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\AddQuestion}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%

      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneb}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwob}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnec}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoc}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOned}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwod}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnee}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoe}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnef}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwof}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneg}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwog}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneh}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoh}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  
      \hspace*{\fill}
       \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom,  resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnea}{\AddTwoa} \hfill   \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white] {\AddOneb}{\AddTwob} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom,  resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnec}{\AddTwoc} \hfill  \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white] {\AddOned}{\AddTwod} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom,  resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnee}{\AddTwoe} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnef}{\AddTwof} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOneg}{\AddTwog} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOneh}{\AddTwoh}  \hspace*{\fill}\\
          ~\newline
          ~\newline

}%
}%





 %\pgfmathsetseed{\number\randomseed}
 \begin{document}


 \vspace{2cm}

 \AddQuestion{5}

 \end{document}
```

again sorry that's this is not the platform for this problem, I just don't know where to start (or indeed if its possible), but any direction would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: You can probably write a terminal script to select random pages and send them to the printer. Which operating system do you use, Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: I'm on a Mac at the moment

Comment: If the  final objective is make exams with random questions or questions in random order for every student, you should know about the `automutiplechoice` package (AMC), better under Linux, so you can use also the GUI to correct the scanned sheets automatically.

Comment: I would not say that you are on the wrong platform: People say TeX is Turing-complete. In any case (La)TeX has great programming-capabilities in terms of macros and expansion. But honestly it is not clear to me what exactly you wish to achieve. I suppose this is because in your question you use the word "page" for denoting different things. Do you wish to create a pdf-file which holds a document which in turn consists of 20 pages, each of the pages holding a set of randomly-generated exercises? This should be feasible in LaTeX. If I got right what your needs are I might elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script works in `zsh` and `bash`, which are two commonly used shells in macOS. It assumes compilation with XeLaTeX (because of `pstricks`) and it needs `gs` (Ghostscript) to be installed. I believe Ghostscript is installed by TeX Live/MacTeX but if not you can install it with `brew install gs` from the Mac terminal.

Script:

```bash
for i in {1..20}
do
   xelatex practiseworksheet.tex
   mv practiseworksheet.pdf worksheetcopy$i.pdf
done
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=exercise20.pdf worksheetcopy*.pdf
```

This script runs XeLaTeX 20 times, copies the output to a numbered file each time, and in the end merges all 20 files together in the file `exercise20.pdf` which you can print as normal.

However, XeLaTeX only updates the random seed once per minute. This means that probably all exercise sheets will be the same (as 20 runs will typically be completed within one minute). To modify this behavior you can set the random seed in the LaTeX code explicitly to the value `\randomseed`, which is different each run. Relevant code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\randomseed}
```

Step by step instructions:

1. Copy the code for the script into a text editor like TextEdit.
2. Make sure the filename of your LaTeX file corresponds to the name in the 3rd and 4th line of the script. Change it if needed. For example if your LaTeX file is called `myfile.tex` then the lines in the script need to be:

   ```bash
   xelatex myfile.tex
   mv myfile.pdf worksheetcopy$i.pdf
   ```
3. Save the script in TextEdit in the same directory as your LaTeX file. Choose as filename for the script file for example `exercise20.sh`.
4. Open a terminal.
5. Navigate to the directory of your LaTeX file using a `cd` command. For example if your LaTeX file is in the directory *Exercises* which is a subdirectory of *My Projects* in your home directory, then you type `cd "My Projects/Exercises"`.
6. Confirm you are in the correct directory by entering `ls`. This lists all files in the current directory. Check if your LaTeX file is listed. If not then you need to use a different `cd` command. Also confirm if the script file is in that directory (with the name `exercise20.sh`).
7. Now, still in the terminal, type `zsh exercise20.sh`. To be clear: *do not* type or copy the script directly into the terminal.
8. The script will run, showing output from LaTeX.
9. After the script has finished, open the Finder and go to the directory.
10. Find the file `exercise20.pdf`, open it and print it.

---

An alternative version with pdflatex instead of xelatex is shown below. For this version `\usepackage{pstricks}` is removed. PSTricks was used only for color specifications such as `\white`, which can be replaced by the more standard `\color{white}` version that does not need PSTricks. This then allows to compile with pdflatex. In that case instead of `\randomseed` you need to use `\pdfrandomseed`.

Document:

```
\documentclass{article}
%AdditionCode
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{xlop}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{~\\56 Problem Practice Worksheet}
\rhead{Name: ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ \\}
\lfoot{Number Correct: ~ \Large $\dfrac{~}{20}$}
\cfoot{~}


\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%
%---------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\AddQuestion}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%

      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneb}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwob}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnec}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoc}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOned}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwod}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnee}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoe}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnef}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwof}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneg}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwog}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneh}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoh}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  
      \hspace*{\fill}
      \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnea} {\AddTwoa} \hfill  \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOneb}{\AddTwob} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnec}{\AddTwoc} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOned}{\AddTwod} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnee}{\AddTwoe} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnef}{\AddTwof} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOneg}{\AddTwog} \hfill \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOneh}{\AddTwoh}  \hspace*{\fill}\\
      ~\newline
      ~\newline

}%
}%

\begin{document}

\vspace{2cm}

\AddQuestion{5}

\end{document}
```

Script:

```bash
for i in {1..20}
do
   pdflatex practiseworksheet.tex
   mv practiseworksheet.pdf worksheetcopy$i.pdf
done
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=exercise20.pdf worksheetcopy*.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this goes above what this platform is for.

Comment: @PaulA next time you can ask something like this on the sister sites [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (for Mac related questions) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) (for questions about shell scripting in general) or even [Super User](https://superuser.com/) which also takes Windows questions. In general "write a script for me" questions are off-topic everywhere but asking about how to approach such a problem is usually ok. In this case `\pgfmathsetseed` did add a bit of LaTeX to the question in the end though.

Comment: @PaulA I have added step by step instructions for using the script. Please let me know if this works for you or if you still have problems, and if so, in which step.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn .Thank you for all your help, I have finally got it to sort of work (which I will forever be in your debt). It does print 20 sheets but only page one is different from the rest which are all the same. Feel free to ignore this, you have provided enough. I think I need to read more on pgfmathsetseed.

Comment: @PaulA I'm not sure why your resulting pdf is not random, when I tested it each page was different. Maybe you did not put `\pgfmathsetseed{\number\randomseed}` in the right place? It is supposed to go in your LaTeX file near the top, below `\usepackage{tikz}`.

Comment: I still can't get this to work I know its my deficiency, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn has been very generous with they time. Is there a forum or site which uses something like team viewer with Latex knowledge?

Comment: @PaulA in your code that is in the question now you use `\pgfmathsetseed{(100)}`. If this is indeed the code you are now using then it makes sense that the output is always the same, because you set the seed to a fixed value of 100. Use `\pgfmathsetseed{\number\randomseed}` instead. Or if that is _not_ the code that you actually use then you should edit the question again and provide the actual code.

Comment: Also, if the screenshot you posted is current, then there are many other problems. XeLaTeX does not seem to work as you get an error about `XeLaTex.fmt`. Ghostscript (`gs`) seems problematic because it complains about a bad CPU type. In the 4th line of the script you use the filename `practiceworkshet.tex` while your real file is called `practiseworksheet.tex`, so with an `s` instead of `c` and two `e`'s, this results in an error message 'No such file or directory' in the terminal. You should fix these problems first and then try again.

Comment: @PaulA finally a practical comment regarding the site: when you want to refer to somebody you should not use the profile url (tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn for me) but instead use the @-notation, i.e., @ followed by the username (so `@Marijn` for me). This will trigger an inbox notification for that person if they participated in the comment discussion in that particular question or answer before. Besides, the person that wrote the question or answer where you comment on is always notified, also when you don't use @.

Comment: Sorry @Marijn, you are going well above and beyond for me. I have changed the spelling errors, I've just been a little frustrated with trying to sort this and missed typed (dyslexia is a B****h). but when I run the code without putting a numerical value in it only produces 1+1=2 (20 times) as the output.

Comment: I just can't see what i'm doing wrong as others have said it works for them?

Comment: @PaulA maybe the problem is caused by XeLaTeX (given that your screenshot shows an error in building the format). I have added an alternative version of the document and the script that uses pdfLaTeX instead. This also changes the way randomness is implemented. You can try this one and see if it produces the correct result.

Comment: You are honestly the best! can I tick it now? @Marijn

Comment: @PaulA I see you already did :) I think that means that it works for you now?