# printing pdfs from a latex code

Tags: pdf, printing

I am trying to print the following code 20 times without having to copy it 20 times, as its a random number generator and I want each sheet to be different I am having trouble.

```
\documentclass{article}
%AdditionCode
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{pstricks}
% \usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{~\\56 Problem Practice Worksheet}
\rhead{Name: ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ \\}
\lfoot{Number Correct: ~ \Large $\dfrac{~}{20}$}
\cfoot{~}


\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%
%---------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\AddQuestion}[1]{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%

       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneb}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwob}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnec}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoc}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOned}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwod}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnee}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoe}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnef}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwof}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneg}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwog}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOneh}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoh}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
  
       \hspace*{\fill}
       \opsub[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnea}   {\AddTwoa} \hfill  \opsub[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOneb}{\AddTwob} \hfill \opsub[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnec}{\AddTwoc} \hfill \opsub[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOned}{\AddTwod} \hfill \opsub[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnee}{\AddTwoe} \hfill \opsub[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOnef}{\AddTwof} \hfill \opsub[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOneg}{\AddTwog} \hfill \opsub[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\white]{\AddOneh}{\AddTwoh}  \hspace*{\fill}\\
              ~\newline
         ~\newline

 }%
 }%

 \begin{document}



  \vspace{2cm}

  \AddQuestion{5}

  \end{document}
```

Somebody has advise me to use Zhs with the following code;

```
for i in {1..20}
do
   xelatex practiseworksheet.tex
   mv practiseworksheet.pdf worksheetcopy$i.pdf
done
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=exercise20.pdf      worksheetcopy*.pdf
```

but I cannot make it work, does anybody have any ideas?

I am sorry and it just might be out of my league but I only get this error: when I try all the advise.[image]

Comment: is this not a duplicate of your previous question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652462/a-printing-quarry

Comment: Sorry I was advised to post here when I had an issue, I did not realise this was a platform for Apple products.

Comment: It is no longer on the apple site it has been moved here to TeX

Comment: Hi @nohillside It is on the printing side, I'm sorry I don't know how to change the loop.

Comment: It works for me if I add `\pgfmathsetseed{\number\randomseed}` at the end of the preamble to get a new random seed each time. (Looks like that was advised in the other thread as well; what's the problem you're having?)

Comment: You misspelled "zsh" as "Zhs", maybe that is part of the problem? The `zsh` command needs to be used in the terminal, correctly spelled. Also, did you change the name of your LaTeX file to `practiseworksheet.tex`, or alternatively change the filename in the script to the actual name of your file? Furthermore there are some spaces now between `exercise20.pdf` and `worksheetcopy*.pdf`, where did they come from? Finally, the script produces a new pdf called `exercise20.pdf` in the same directory, so it does not print directly, you need to open that file and print it, was that clear?

Comment: Also, as general advice: you should not upvote and accept an answer before you test it and confirm that it works for you. If it does not work, ask for clarification from the answerer (in this case me), in the comments below the answer, and don't ask another question right away.

Comment: Sorry I will try to keep that in mind from now on, I was just trying to show my thanks, I'm not used to this type of community.

Comment: @PaulA no problem, indeed it is different from other sites, but if you spend some time here you will soon learn how everything works.

Comment: I have added my terminal screen shot as I don't seem to be able to find the file, even when I just run a find command, am I out of my depth and can anybody help with a forum that could help?

Comment: Your screenshot appears to show `for` mistyped as `or`, which the shell does not recognise, the rest of your code relies on the `for` loop so everything breaks from there

Comment: Thanks for everyones help but I don't think I have the skills to do this, I have tried everything suggested (which is why I love this forum).

Comment: @PaulA I will try to add some clarifications to the other question, that seems a better place to try to solve the issues.