# separate random questions and answer onto different pages

Tags: macros, pdf, pgfmath

I can create simple random addition questions, but when I try to separate the question and the answers onto 2 separate pages, I assume because its a random generator the answer sheet is not the same as the question sheet.

```
\documentclass{article}
%AdditionCode
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{xlop}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%
%---------------------------------------%
\newcommand{\AddQuestion}[1]{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%

         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}
 
  
 question one     
  \opadd[carryadd=false, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{white}]{\AddOnea}  {\AddTwoa} \\

      ~\newline
 Answer two
      \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\color{black}]{\AddOnea}   {\AddTwoa} \\
  
}%
}%


\begin{document}

\AddQuestion{2}

\end{document}
```

This is not the full code for the worksheet just didn't want to post loads of code.

Comment: Note that the answers are actually there in the pdf, just rendered in white so you don't see them (they will become visible if you select them with the mouse). If you have a recent version of Ghostscript (9.54 minimum, you can check with `gs --version`) then there is a rendering parameter `-dBlackText` that you can use to make all text black in an existing pdf, for example the exercise sheets: `gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dBlackText -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=answers20.pdf exercise20.pdf`.

Comment: Are you familar with [How to create multipage tables of binary arithmetical problems (and associated answers) involving pseudo-random numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368643/5001)?

Comment: sorry @Marijn I was not specific enough, I know the question has a white answer, but I would like to duplicate this with the carryadd=true, \color{black} answer printed on a separate page. but when I try this it produces a different random question.

Comment: @PaulA - You need to choose and fix the same random seed for both the question and answer parts.

Comment: My comment was aimed at the following workflow: run LaTeX to generate the 20 exercise sheets with white answers, then after this has finished run Ghostscript on the final pdf to convert all text to black. Then you get two files, one with black exercises+white answers, one with black exercises+black answers. If you want the carryadd printed in the answers but not in the questions you can still use that comment, by using `carryadd=true, carrystyle=\scriptsize\color{white}` in the questions.

Comment: Once again above and beyond, I love this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can use the package *zref*:

The following example could be a starting-point:

In all latex-runs retrieve values of pseudo-random-variables from zref-labels.
In the first latex-run create values for pseudo-random-variables via pseudo-random generator.
In consecutive latex-runs obtain values for pseudo-random-variables from zref-labels.
In all latex-runs store values of pseudo-random-variables in zref-labels.

In order to get everything right you need to compile at least twice without deleting aux-files between latex-runs.

With *xlop* to each character of a result/carry/operand/intermediary number/remainder an instance of the corresponding style-macro is applied.

Therefore in the first LaTeX-run, where zref-labels are not defined yet,

- style-macros `\undefinedstyle`/`\undefinedcarrystyle` are used that deliver question-marks.
- `\zref@extractdefault` defaults everything to 0 so that both operands and calculations/results yield 0, a digit-sequence which consists of a single character so that only one instance of the corresponding question-mark-delivering style-macro is applied.

In consecutive LaTeX-runs zref-labels are defined and values of pseudo-random-variables should be retrieved properly.

Where in consecutive LaTeX-runs answers are undesired `resultstyle=\phantom` instead of `resultstyle=\color{white}` is used and carries are done as `\phantom`s, too, via `carrystyle=\phantomcarrystyle`.
I am not quite sure if this is a good idea. But this way results are not in the pdf-file at all in the places where they shall not be seen, and therefore people cannot blindly copy-paste results from these places/cannot use GhostScript-trickery for making results visible in these places.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{xlop}

\usepackage{zref}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{AddOnea}{0}%
\zref@newprop{AddTwoa}{0}%
\zref@newprop{range}{0}%
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%
%---------------------------------------%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\undefinedstyle[1]{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}%
\newcommand\undefinedcarrystyle[1]{{\nfss@text{\reset@font\scriptsize\bfseries ??}}}%
\newcommand\phantomcarrystyle[1]{\phantom{\scriptsize{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\AddQuestions}[2]{%
    \zref@setcurrent{range}{#1}%
    \zref@labelbyprops{#2}{range}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
         \par\ifnum\i=1 \else\medskip\fi\noindent\hbox{Question \i: }%
         \zref@ifrefundefined{#2.\i}{%
           \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
           \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}%
           \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\AddOnea}{\zref@setcurrent{AddOnea}}%
           \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\AddTwoa}{\zref@setcurrent{AddTwoa}}%
         }{%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
             \zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddOnea}{0}%
           }{\zref@setcurrent{AddOnea}}%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
             \zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddTwoa}{0}%
           }{\zref@setcurrent{AddTwoa}}%
         }%
         \zref@labelbyprops{#2.\i}{AddOnea, AddTwoa}%
         \zref@refused{#2.\i}%
         \zref@ifrefundefined{#2.\i}{%
           % actually setting carrystyle is not needed as there are no carries with defaults 0, but ...
           \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\undefinedstyle, operandstyle=\undefinedstyle, carrystyle=\undefinedcarrystyle]%
         }{%
           % Only operands shall be seen, so turn everything else into \phantom
           \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\phantom, carrystyle=\phantomcarrystyle]%
         }%
         {\zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddOnea}{0}}%
         {\zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddTwoa}{0}}%
    }%
    \par
}%
\newcommand{\AddAnswers}[1]{%
    \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
      \zref@refused{#1}%
      \par\noindent
      {\normalfont\bfseries [Question-series ``#1'' undefined, probably re-run latex, see messages on console/in .log-file]}%
      \par
     }{%    
      \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
         \romannumeral0% 
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Exchange
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
            \zref@extractdefault{#1}{range}{1}%
         }{ 1,...,}%
      }{\foreach \i in }{%
           \par\ifnum\i=1 \else\medskip\fi\noindent\hbox{\rlap{Answer \i: }\phantom{Question \i: }}%
           \zref@refused{#1.\i}%
           \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom]%
                 {\zref@extractdefault{#1.\i}{AddOnea}{0}}%
                 {\zref@extractdefault{#1.\i}{AddTwoa}{0}}%
      }%
    }%
    \par
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent Here come the questions with answers:
\AddAnswers{This question-series label}%

\newpage

\noindent Here come the questions without answers:
\AddQuestions{10}{This question-series label}%

\newpage

\noindent Here come the questions with answers again:
\AddAnswers{This question-series label}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

If you wish, e.g., to have 20 exam-sheets, each sheet holding another set of 15 randomly generated exercises, you can combine the above with a loop for replicating a set of tokens k times:

`\DoKtimes{⟨TeX-number-quantity of value K⟩}{⟨tokens⟩}`

On the console and in the .log-file obey the message
`LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`
, i.e., compile as often as needed without deleting aux-files between latex-runs for that message not occurring any more.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%%  \DoKtimes{<TeX-number-quantity of value K>}{<tokens>}
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\DoKtimes[2]{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\DoKtimesloop\expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}{}%
}%
\newcommand\DoKtimesloop[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#3}{%
    \expandafter\DoKtimesloop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3#2}%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\zref@newprop{AddOnea}{0}%
\zref@newprop{AddTwoa}{0}%
\zref@newprop{range}{0}%
\newcommand\undefinedstyle[1]{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}%
\newcommand\undefinedcarrystyle[1]{{\nfss@text{\reset@font\scriptsize\bfseries ??}}}%
\newcommand\phantomcarrystyle[1]{\phantom{\scriptsize{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\AddQuestions}[2]{%
    \zref@setcurrent{range}{#1}%
    \zref@labelbyprops{#2}{range}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
         \par\ifnum\i=1 \else\medskip\fi\noindent\hbox{Question \i: }%
         \zref@ifrefundefined{#2.\i}{%
           \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
           \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}%
           \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\AddOnea}{\zref@setcurrent{AddOnea}}%
           \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\AddTwoa}{\zref@setcurrent{AddTwoa}}%
         }{%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
             \zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddOnea}{0}%
           }{\zref@setcurrent{AddOnea}}%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
             \zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddTwoa}{0}%
           }{\zref@setcurrent{AddTwoa}}%
         }%
         \zref@labelbyprops{#2.\i}{AddOnea, AddTwoa}%
         \zref@refused{#2.\i}%
         \zref@ifrefundefined{#2.\i}{%
           % actually setting carrystyle is not needed as there are no carries with defaults 0, but ...
           \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\undefinedstyle, operandstyle=\undefinedstyle, carrystyle=\undefinedcarrystyle]%
         }{%
           % Only operands shall be seen, so turn everything else into \phantom
           \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\phantom, carrystyle=\phantomcarrystyle]%
         }%
         {\zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddOnea}{0}}%
         {\zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddTwoa}{0}}%
    }%
    \par
}%
\newcommand{\AddAnswers}[1]{%
    \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
      \zref@refused{#1}%
      \par\noindent
      {\normalfont\bfseries [Question-series ``#1'' undefined, probably re-run latex, see messages on console/in .log-file]}%
      \par
     }{%    
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
         \romannumeral 
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
            \zref@extractdefault{#1}{range}{1}%
         }{\UD@stopromannumeral 1,...,}%
      }{\foreach \i in }{%
           \par\ifnum\i=1 \else\medskip\fi\noindent\hbox{\rlap{Answer \i: }\phantom{Question \i: }}%
           \zref@refused{#1.\i}%
           \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom]%
                 {\zref@extractdefault{#1.\i}{AddOnea}{0}}%
                 {\zref@extractdefault{#1.\i}{AddTwoa}{0}}%
      }%
    }%
    \par
}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%
%%=============================================================================
%% A dirty hack for resetting page-numbers with each sheet
\newcommand\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber{0}%
\newcommand\resetpage{%
  \newpage
  \xdef\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber{\number\numexpr\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber+1\relax}%
  \zref@labelbyprops{pagereset-\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber}{page}%
}%
\newcommand\obtainlastresetpage{%
  \zref@extractdefault{pagereset-\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber}{page}{0}%
}%
\newcommand\ps@resetableplain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\@arabic{\number\numexpr\value{page}-\obtainlastresetpage+1\relax}\hfil}%
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot 
}%

\makeatother

\pagestyle{resetableplain}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%
%% Create 20 sheets of paper, each holding 15 randomly generated exercises without answers:
% Initialize the macro for counting sheets to 0:
\newcommand\sheetNumber{0}%
\DoKtimes{20}{%
  \resetpage
  % Increment \sheetNumber
  \edef\sheetNumber{\number\numexpr\sheetNumber+1\relax}%
  \section*{Question sheet \sheetNumber (without answers)}
  \AddQuestions{15}{This question-series-sheet-\sheetNumber-label}%
}%
%%%%%%%
%% Re-create the 20 sheets of paper from above, this time with answers:
% Initialize the macro for counting sheets to 0:
\renewcommand\sheetNumber{0}%
\DoKtimes{20}{%
  \resetpage
  % Increment \sheetNumber
  \edef\sheetNumber{\number\numexpr\sheetNumber+1\relax}%
  \section*{Question sheet \sheetNumber (with answers)}
  \AddAnswers{This question-series-sheet-\sheetNumber-label}%
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

If you wish to individualize the sheets, e.g., to have the name of the examinee, you can, e.g., define a loop, which iterates on a list of undelimited arguments, defining a macro from each name and doing *⟨tokens⟩*:

```
\DefineVariableWithEachAndDo{⟨(already defined) macro holding list of undelimited arguments⟩}%
                            {⟨macro (to be (re)defined in each iteration) holding current element of list⟩}%
                            {⟨tokens⟩}
```

On the console and in the .log-file obey the message
`LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`
, i.e., compile as often as needed without deleting aux-files between latex-runs for that message not occurring any more.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%%  \DefineVariableWithEachAndDo{<macro holding list of undelimited arguments>}%
%%                              {<macro holding current element of list>}%
%%                              {<tokens>}
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\DefineVariableWithEachAndDo[3]{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter{#1}{\DefineVariableWithEachAndDoloop{#2}{#3}{}}{\relax}%
}%
\newcommand\DefineVariableWithEachAndDoloop[4]{%
  \ifx\relax#4\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\fi
  {\UD@stopromannumeral#3}{%
    \DefineVariableWithEachAndDoloop{#1}{#2}{#3\def#1{#4}#2}%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\zref@newprop{AddOnea}{0}%
\zref@newprop{AddTwoa}{0}%
\zref@newprop{range}{0}%
\newcommand\undefinedstyle[1]{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}%
\newcommand\undefinedcarrystyle[1]{{\nfss@text{\reset@font\scriptsize\bfseries ??}}}%
\newcommand\phantomcarrystyle[1]{\phantom{\scriptsize{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\AddQuestions}[2]{%
    \zref@setcurrent{range}{#1}%
    \zref@labelbyprops{#2}{range}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
         \par\ifnum\i=1 \else\medskip\fi\noindent\hbox{Question \i: }%
         \zref@ifrefundefined{#2.\i}{%
           \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddOnea}{random(\DifficultyOne)}%
           \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\AddTwoa}{random(\DifficultyTwo)}%
           \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\AddOnea}{\zref@setcurrent{AddOnea}}%
           \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\AddTwoa}{\zref@setcurrent{AddTwoa}}%
         }{%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
             \zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddOnea}{0}%
           }{\zref@setcurrent{AddOnea}}%
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
             \zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddTwoa}{0}%
           }{\zref@setcurrent{AddTwoa}}%
         }%
         \zref@labelbyprops{#2.\i}{AddOnea, AddTwoa}%
         \zref@refused{#2.\i}%
         \zref@ifrefundefined{#2.\i}{%
           % actually setting carrystyle is not needed as there are no carries with defaults 0, but ...
           \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\undefinedstyle, operandstyle=\undefinedstyle, carrystyle=\undefinedcarrystyle]%
         }{%
           % Only operands shall be seen, so turn everything else into \phantom
           \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom, resultstyle=\phantom, carrystyle=\phantomcarrystyle]%
         }%
         {\zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddOnea}{0}}%
         {\zref@extractdefault{#2.\i}{AddTwoa}{0}}%
    }%
    \par
}%
\newcommand{\AddAnswers}[1]{%
    \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
      \zref@refused{#1}%
      \par\noindent
      {\normalfont\bfseries [Question-series ``#1'' undefined, probably re-run latex, see messages on console/in .log-file]}%
      \par
     }{%    
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
         \romannumeral 
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
            \zref@extractdefault{#1}{range}{1}%
         }{\UD@stopromannumeral 1,...,}%
      }{\foreach \i in }{%
           \par\ifnum\i=1 \else\medskip\fi\noindent\hbox{\rlap{Answer \i: }\phantom{Question \i: }}%
           \zref@refused{#1.\i}%
           \opadd[carryadd=true, voperator=bottom]%
                 {\zref@extractdefault{#1.\i}{AddOnea}{0}}%
                 {\zref@extractdefault{#1.\i}{AddTwoa}{0}}%
      }%
    }%
    \par
}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyOne}{999}%
\newcommand*{\DifficultyTwo}{99}%
%%=============================================================================
%% A dirty hack for resetting page-numbers with each sheet
\newcommand\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber{0}%
\newcommand\resetpage{%
  \newpage
  \xdef\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber{\number\numexpr\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber+1\relax}%
  \zref@labelbyprops{pagereset-\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber}{page}%
}%
\newcommand\obtainlastresetpage{%
  \zref@extractdefault{pagereset-\resetpagezreflabelnamenumber}{page}{0}%
}%
\newcommand\ps@resetableplain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\@arabic{\number\numexpr\value{page}-\obtainlastresetpage+1\relax}\hfil}%
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot 
}%

\makeatother

\pagestyle{resetableplain}

\newcommand\ExamineeNameList{%
  {Coby}%
  {Johan}%
  {Rudy}%
  {Rodrigo}%
  {Alejandra}%
  {Oswaldo}%
  {Yusuf}%
  {Luz}%
  {Denzel}%
  {Abigayle}%
  {Bobby}%
  {Margaret}%
  {Eli}%
  {Billy}%
  {Jazmine}%
  {Miguel}%
  {Jon}%
  {Valentin}%
  {Lance}%
  {Skyler}%
}%
\newcommand\ThisExamimeesName{}% <- This raises an error if the macro is already in use by some package/by some other code.

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%
%% Create a sheet of 15 ramdom questions for each examinee:
\DefineVariableWithEachAndDo{\ExamineeNameList}{\ThisExamimeesName}{%
  \resetpage
  \section*{Question sheet without answers for \ThisExamimeesName}%
  \AddQuestions{15}{This question-series-sheet-\ThisExamimeesName-label}%
}%
%%%%%%%
%% Re-create the sheets from above, this time with answers:
\DefineVariableWithEachAndDo{\ExamineeNameList}{\ThisExamimeesName}{%
  \resetpage
  \section*{Question sheet with answers for \ThisExamimeesName}%
  \AddAnswers{This question-series-sheet-\ThisExamimeesName-label}%
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich Diez I just need to work out how to rework the code to make different worksheets like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652462/a-printing-quarry/652471?noredirect=1#comment1626990_652471 but that's an other issue, your solution is great. If you have the time can you explain why I have to run it twice? just so I can learn.

Comment: @PaulA The package zref is used which provides macros for storing in and retrieving from the .aux-files almost arbitrary data in the same way in which the kernel's `\refstepcounter`/`\label`/`\ref`-cross-referencing-mechanism stores/retrieves page-numbers and values of LaTeX-counters via the .aux-files. In the first latex-run there are no .aux-files yet, from which data can be retrieved so attempts at retrieving yield `??`.   Aux-files are created during the first LaTeX-run. With subsequent runs existing .aux-files are read and destroyed at the beginning and created anew during the run.

Comment: @PaulA In my answer to [How to prevent reference to enumeration inside new environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442118/118714) I tried to explain the cross-referencing-mechanism of LaTeX 2e. zref is quite similar: `\refstepcounter` corresponds to `\zref@setcurrent`. `\label` corresponds to `\zref@labelbyprops` but with `\zref@labelbyprops` by specifying properties you specify what data to store. `\ref`/`\pageref` correspond to `\zref@extractdefault` but with `\zref@extractdefault` by specifying properties you specify what data to retrieve.

Comment: Thank you so much for help this is amazing @Ulrich Diez. I am completely new to this type of code can point me to a line to which could change the sheet to subtraction or multiplication, I assume division is not possible, in the English style.